# If-Statements and integrate() function in R

Tags: r, if-statement, numerical-integration

Do if statements not work for integrate?  I have to do something much more complicated than this, but I am supplying this example because it isolated the problem.

```
Kernel = function(x){
  if(abs(x)<1){
    w = 1 - abs(x)
  } else{
    w = 0 
  }
  return(w)
}


integrate(Kernel, 
          0, 
          1)
```

The error message:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: This is not a vectorized function. Use `ifelse` instead

Comment: Integrate passes a vector to the given function, so `x` will be many elements long in your function. You could try `ifelse` instead of `if...else` if you want your function to take vectors. Alternatively you could wrap your function with `vectorize`

Answer (score 1):

```
Kernel = function(x){
  pmax(1-abs(x), 0)
}


integrate(Kernel, 0, 1)
0.5 with absolute error < 5.6e-15
```

or even:

```
Kernel1 = function(x){
  ifelse(abs(x)<1,  1-abs(x), 0)
}


integrate(Kernel1, 0, 1)
0.5 with absolute error < 5.6e-15
```

If you want to maintain the way you have written your function, you have to vectorize it:

```
Kernel2 = function(x){
  ifelse(abs(x)< 1, 1-abs(x), 0)
  if(abs(x)<1){
    w = 1 - abs(x)
  } else{
    w = 0 
  }
  return(w)
}


integrate(Vectorize(Kernel2), 0, 1)
0.5 with absolute error < 5.6e-15
```